# Error passing "--priority=low" option to gradle from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Gradle has a `--priority=low` command-line option to run e.g. compiler processes with a lower priority.

It works fine for builds started from a command line.

To apply this option to builds started from within Android Studio I add the `--priority=low` option into "Command-line Options" in "File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler".
However upon a build start it produces an error

> Unknown command-line option '--priority'.

Other options (e.g. `--offline`, `-P` options..) work fine from within Android Studio though.

How to pass the `--priority=low` option from Android Studio to gradle builds?

Android Studio is the latest version available (2020.3.1 patch 4). Gradle is set to run as a daemon (a default option).

Update: there had been no answers so far, so I consider it a bug, I filed it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211840079

Update 2: Google's answer:

> Status: Won't Fix (Infeasible)
>
> Not all command line flags can be passed to a running daemon. Use
> gradle.properties file to configure these properties. See:
> https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html.